# IntelliJ losing modules after Github cloning

Tags: git, intellij-idea, module

I'm working with a friend on a common repository on Github.

He pushed this project: A main module called PCADGame with 2 submodules called Client and Server.

We wrote a gitignore file following the [official support page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems):

> - All the files under .idea directory in the project root except the  workspace.xml and tasks.xml files which store user specific settings
> - All the .iml module files that can be located in different module directories(applies to IntelliJ IDEA).
>     Blockquote

I pulled the project and everything works fine but the two submodules Client and Server are now two standard directories.

[image]

I've tried to set them manually as module, but something went wrong (with the classpath ?) and the IDE cannot recognize where to found my main class.

Is there a standard way to handle this situation ?

---

My gitignore file

[image]

Comment: Please show your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misinterpreted what you read. The IML files define the modules. Those **should** be checked in and **not** be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in the past, to solve it I did the following:

Under preferences -> Version Control -> Ignored Files.
See if any files are being erroneously ignored, and remove them from the list if they are.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately the ignored files section is empty in my project.